# android fragment android.support.v4.app.Fragment; error

Tags: android

i currently have a working project that uses fragment to select layouts from the list , how ever what am trying to do now is add 1 class and layout fragfrant from a different project and am getting this error.

android.support.v4.app.Fragment; when i high light the line.

```
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;




public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    // drawer layout
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    // drawer listview
    private ListView drawerListView;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // toggle that open and close the drawer
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // Set the adapter for the list view
        drawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, navMenuTitles));
        // Set the list's click listener
        drawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);


        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, /* Context */
                drawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.string.app_name, /* nav drawer open - description for accessibility */
                R.string.app_name /* nav drawer close - description for accessibility */
        );
//        {
//
//            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
//            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
//                setTitle(mTitle);
////                calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
//                invalidateOptionsMenu();
//            }
//
//            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
//            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
//                setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
////                calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
//                invalidateOptionsMenu();
//            }
//        };

        // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
//            on first time display view for first nav item
            selectFragment(0);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns
        // true, then it has handled the app icon touch event

        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /***
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(drawerListView);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    private class SlideMenuClickListener
            implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectFragment(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectFragment(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                break;

            case 1:
                fragment = new InboxFragment();
                break;

            case 2:
                fragment = new SentFragment();
                break;

            case 3:
                fragment = new DraftFragment();
                break;
            case 4:
                fragment = new Maaidah();
                break;
            case 5:
                fragment = new anaam();
                break;
            case 6:
                fragment = new araaf();
                break;
            case 7:
                fragment = new anfal();
                break;
            case 8:
                fragment = new taubah();
                break;
            case 9:
                fragment = new yunus();
                break;
            case 10:
                fragment = new Hood();
                break;
            case 11:
                fragment = new yusuf();
                break;
            case 12:
                fragment = new raad();
                break;
            case 13:
                fragment = new ibrahim();
                break;
            case 14:
                fragment = new hijr();
                break;
            case 15:
                fragment = new nahl();
                break;
            case 16:
                fragment = new israil();
                break;
            case 17:
                fragment = new kahfi();
                break;
            case 18:
                fragment = new mariyam();
                break;
            case 19:
                fragment = new taha();
                break;
            case 20:
                fragment = new anbia();
                break;
            case 21:
                fragment = new haj();
                break;
            case 22:
                fragment = new muminun();
                break;
            case 23:
                fragment = new nur();
                break;
            case 24:
                fragment = new furqan();
                break;
            case 25:
                fragment = new shuara();
                break;
            case 26:
                fragment = new naml();
                break;
            case 27:
                fragment = new qasas();
                break;
            case 28:
                fragment = new ankabut();
                break;
            case 29:
                fragment = new roam();
                break;
            case 30:
                fragment = new luqman();
                break;
            case 31:
                fragment = new sajdah();
                break;
            case 32:
                fragment = new ahzaab();
                break;
            case 33:
                fragment = new saba();
                break;
            case 34:
                fragment = new fatir();
                break;
            case 35:
                fragment = new yaasin();
                break;
            case 36:
                fragment = new safaat();
                break;
            case 37:
                fragment = new soaad();
                break;
            case 38:
                fragment = new zumar();
                break;
            case 39:
                fragment = new mumin();
                break;
            case 40:
                fragment = new sajadah();
                break;
            case 41:
                fragment = new shuara();
                break;
            case 42:
                fragment = new zukhraf();
                break;
            case 43:
                fragment = new dukhan();
                break;
            case 44:
                fragment = new jaasiah();
                break;
            case 45:
                fragment = new ahqaaf();
                break;
            case 46:
                fragment = new muhammad();
                break;
            case 47:
                fragment = new fath();
                break;
            case 48:
                fragment = new hujurat();
                break;
            case 49:
                fragment = new qaaf();
                break;
            case 50:
                fragment = new zaariyat();
                break;
            case 51:
                fragment = new toor();
                break;
            case 52:
                fragment = new najm();
                break;
            case 53:
                fragment = new qamar();
                break;
            case 54:
                fragment = new rahmaan();
                break;
            case 55:
                fragment = new waqiah();
                break;
            case 56:
                fragment = new hadeed();
                break;
            case 57:
                fragment = new mujadilah();
                break;
            case 58:
                fragment = new hashar();
                break;
            case 59:
                fragment = new mumtahnah();
                break;
            case 60:
                fragment = new saf();
                break;
            case 61:
                fragment = new jumuah();
                break;
            case 62:
                fragment = new munafiqun();
                break;
            case 63:
                fragment = new taghabun();
                break;
            case 64:
                fragment = new talaq();
                break;
            case 65:
                fragment = new tahrim();
                break;
            case 66:
                fragment = new mulk();
                break;
            case 67:
                fragment = new qalam();
                break;
            case 68:
                fragment = new haaqah();
                break;
            case 69:
                fragment = new meaarij();
                break;
            case 70:
                fragment = new nooh();
                break;
            case 71:
                fragment = new jin();
                break;
            case 72:
                fragment = new muzammil();
                break;
            case 73:
                fragment = new mudassir();
                break;
            case 74:
                fragment = new qiyamah();
                break;
            case 75:
                fragment = new dahar();
                break;
            case 76:
                fragment = new mursalaat();
                break;
            case 77:
                fragment = new naba();
                break;
            case 78:
                fragment = new naziaat();
                break;
            case 79:
                fragment = new abas();
                break;
            case 80:
                fragment = new takwir();
                break;
            case 81:
                fragment = new lnfitar();
                break;
            case 82:
                fragment = new mutaffifin();
                break;
            case 83:
                fragment = new inshiqaq();
                break;
            case 84:
                fragment = new buruj();
                break;
            case 85:
                fragment = new talaq();
                break;
            case 86:
                fragment = new aala();
                break;
            case 87:
                fragment = new ghashiyah();
                break;
            case 88:
                fragment = new fajr();
                break;
            case 89:
                fragment = new balad();
                break;
            case 90:
                fragment = new shams();
                break;
            case 91:
                fragment = new lail();
                break;
            case 92:
                fragment = new duha();
                break;
            case 93:
                fragment = new nashrah();
                break;
            case 94:
                fragment = new teen();
                break;
            case 95:
                fragment = new alaq();
                break;
            case 96:
                fragment = new qadr();
                break;
            case 97:
                fragment = new bayyinah();
                break;
            case 98:
                fragment = new zilzali();
                break;
            case 99:
                fragment = new adiyaat();
                break;
            case 100:
                fragment = new qariah();
                break;
            case 101:
                fragment = new takasur();
                break;
            case 102:
                fragment = new asr();
                break;
            case 103:
                fragment = new humazah();
                break;
            case 104:
                fragment = new feel();
                break;
            case 105:
                fragment = new quraish();
                break;
            case 106:
                fragment = new maoon();
                break;
            case 107:
                fragment = new kausar();
                break;
            case 108:
                fragment = new kafirun();
                break;
            case 109:
                fragment = new nasr();
                break;
            case 110:
                fragment = new tabbat();
                break;
            case 111:
                fragment = new ikhlas();
                break;
            case 112:
                fragment = new falaq();
                break;
            case 113:
                fragment = new naas();
                break;
            case 114:
                fragment = new KaabaLocatorFragment();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            drawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
            drawerListView.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerListView);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }

    }
}
```

i get the error on  case 114 **KaabaLocatorFragment()**
when i highlight this line it says

required  android.support.v4.app.Fragment
found it.bellotti.navigationdrawer.compass.KaabaLocatorFragment

also the case 114 is new line i just added to this project , i wanted to just ad a compass layout and class to this project so here is the line am having problem
**here is  kaabalocatorFragment**

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

import it.bellotti.navigationdrawer.BuildConfig;
import it.bellotti.navigationdrawer.R;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class KaabaLocatorFragment extends Fragment implements Constants, OnMapReadyCallback, SensorEventListener {

  Location mLastLocation;
  MapFragment mMapFragment;
  GoogleMap mMap;

//  private float currentDegree = 0f;
  private SensorManager mSensorManager;

  private float[] mRotationMatrix = new float[16];
  private float[] mValues = new float[3];

  private boolean mRegistered = false;
  private static boolean sWriterExternalPermissionDenied;

  public KaabaLocatorFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
  }

  public static KaabaLocatorFragment newInstance(Location location) {
    KaabaLocatorFragment fragment = new KaabaLocatorFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelable(EXTRA_LAST_LOCATION, location);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
      mLastLocation = (Location) getArguments().getParcelable(EXTRA_LAST_LOCATION);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.SENSOR_SERVICE);
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_kaaba_locator, container, false);
    checkPermissions();

    return view;
  }

  private boolean checkPermissions() {
    if (!PermissionUtil.hasSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
      if (!sWriterExternalPermissionDenied) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL);
      } else {
        // Perhaps inform the user why they aren't seeing anything.
      }
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  public void showMap() {
    if (!PermissionUtil.hasSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission should be granted before this method is called.");
    }

    if (mMapFragment == null) {
      mMapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("map_fragment");
    }

    if (mMapFragment == null) {
      GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions()
              .rotateGesturesEnabled(false)
              .tiltGesturesEnabled(false)
              .compassEnabled(true)
              .zoomControlsEnabled(false)
              .zoomGesturesEnabled(true)
              .scrollGesturesEnabled(true);
      mMapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance(options);
    }

    if (mMap == null && !mMapFragment.isAdded()) {
      ((ViewGroup) getView().findViewById(R.id.map_container)).removeAllViews();
      getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.map_container, mMapFragment, "map_fragment").commit();
      mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    } else {
      registerRotationListener();
    }
  }

  public void hideMap() {
    unregisterRotationListener();
  }

  @Override
  public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    mMap = map;
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
      initMap();
    }
  }

  private void initMap() {
    if (mMap == null && mLastLocation == null) {
      Log.w("KabaaLocatorFragment", "Ignoring since mMap or mLastLocation is null");
      return;
    }

    registerRotationListener();

    LatLng startPosition = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
    //21.4224698,39.8262066
    LatLng kaaba = new LatLng(21.4224698, 39.8262066);

    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(startPosition, 13));
    //mMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);

    mMap.clear();

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .title(getString(R.string.kaaba))
        .position(kaaba));

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.compass))
        .title(getString(R.string.current_location))
        .position(startPosition));

    // Polylines are useful for marking paths and routes on the map.
    mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().geodesic(true)
        .add(startPosition)  // user position
        .add(kaaba)
        .color(Color.RED));  // Kaabah

  }

  public void setLocation(Location location) {
    mLastLocation = location;
    initMap();
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerRotationListener();
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterRotationListener();
  }

  private void registerRotationListener() {
    if (mMap != null && mLastLocation != null && !mRegistered) {
      mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
      mRegistered = true;
    }
  }

  private void unregisterRotationListener() {
    if (mRegistered) {
      mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
      mRegistered = false;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (mLastLocation == null) {
      return;
    }
    SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(mRotationMatrix, event.values);
    SensorManager.getOrientation(mRotationMatrix, mValues);

    /*
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      System.out.println("sensorChanged (" + Math.toDegrees(mValues[0]) + ", " + Math.toDegrees(mValues[1]) + ", " + Math.toDegrees(mValues[2]) + ")");
    }
    */

    float bearing = 0f;

    if (mMap != null) {
      bearing = Double.valueOf(mMap.getCameraPosition().bearing).floatValue();
    }

    // get the angle around the z-axis rotated
    float degree = Double.valueOf(Math.toDegrees(mValues[0])).floatValue();

    if (Math.round(bearing) == Math.round(degree)) {
      System.out.println("bearing and degrees are the same.");
      return;
    }

    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      System.out.println("degrees " + degree + ", bearing " + bearing);
    }

    //tvHeading.setText("Heading: " + Float.toString(degree) + " degrees");

    CameraPosition cameraPosition = mMap.getCameraPosition();
    CameraPosition newPosition = new CameraPosition(cameraPosition.target, cameraPosition.zoom, cameraPosition.tilt, degree);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(newPosition));
    // create a rotation animation (reverse turn degree degrees)
    /*
    RotateAnimation ra = new RotateAnimation(
            currentDegree,
            -degree-180,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.5f);

    // how long the animation will take place
    ra.setDuration(210);

    // set the animation after the end of the reservation status
    ra.setFillAfter(true);

    // Start the animation
    mCompass.startAnimation(ra);
    currentDegree = -degree-180;
    */
  }

  @Override
  public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

  }

  /**
   * Callback received when a permissions request has been completed.
   */
  @Override
  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                         int[] grantResults) {

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL) {
      if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
       showMap();
      } else {
        Log.i("BaseActivity", "LOCATION permission was NOT granted.");
        sWriterExternalPermissionDenied = true;
      }

    } else {
      super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to extend android.support.v4.app.Fragment instead of android.app.Fragment in your KaabaLocatorFragment.

Comment: Do you seriously have a switch with 114 case statements in your code? And you are worried about some compile error? That switch is terrible I can't believe you were even motivated enough to type all that. Also the constant commenting drives me insane. You do know that code without comments is a million times more legible than code with comments? Especially when there is one useless comment after another. Legally every second line. Why? Just why?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the support library v4 on your MainActivity, but the fragment KaabaLocatorFragment is using the native fragment.

The fragment KaabaLocatorFragment need to extends the support.v4 library

Inside the KaabaLocatorFragment, try change this:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

to this

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```